# Disk corrupted after failing FileVault decryption

Tags: macos, filevault

Yesterday my 13inch 2016 MacBook Pro with 500G storage space notified me that my storage was almost full. I checked "About This Mac/Storage" and found out that "System" took more than 200GB of space. After I did much searching on how to reduce the size of "System", none of them suits me (such as deleting Time Machine backups which I never configured or install some tools to analyze my disk which all ended up 200+GB space were inaccessible and protected by the operating system ).

This was when this whole disaster started. While I was searching, I saw some people and a YouTube video pointed out that FileVault takes up much storage to do its encryption, so I tried to turn off FileVault. As FileVault showed that the remaining decrypting time was around 2hrs, I left my Mac aside and returned after 4hrs. The decryption window disappeared which I thought it meant it finished decrypting. Then I tried to reboot my Mac, but nothing happened after I clicked "Shut Down" and there was also no response to any apps on my dock or Launchpad, the only thing I could do was closing all remaining opened windows of apps. So, I forced shutdown  my Mac by long pressing the power button. When I tried to boot my Mac, a question mark folder appeared. Then I accessed Recovery mode to Disk Utility. The "Macintosh HD" partition was missing, only remained Preboot, Recovery, VM these three partitions. I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGl92.jpg) after typing the diskutil command in terminal. The red arrow is where its partition name should be "Macintosh HD" but now the name is missing. Though I tried to changed its name by typing:

```
diskutil rename disk2s1 "Macintosh HD"
```

it responses "Volume must be mounted".

So I typed:

```
diskutil mountDisk disk2s1
```

though it repsonses "Volume(s) mounted successfully", I still get "Volume must be mounted" when I attempt to change the partition's name.

In the /Volume directory, there's only OS X Base System, Preboot, Recovery, VM.

Can anyone please help me? There are tons of important files that I haven't backup yet. Even if I need to wipe my Mac and reinstall MacOS in the end, I still want to backup my files first.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! I’m so sorry about what happened with your encryption experience. Unfortunately, recovery may be very difficult, if not impossible. The best thing to do is __stop__ using the computer and seek recovery options. Good luck.

Comment: @juniorRubyist  recovery options?

Comment: I would recommend grabbing another disk that is larger or same capacity to back up to and trying recovery tools like PhotoRec. (I’ve accidentally formatted my only backup of everything before!) If you are in doubt, seek a professional.